# Save/view files within app

Tags: ios, objective-c

By using X Code, how can I save files inside an app I am creating that contains labels and textfields that the User has put their information in?

Furthermore, once that information is saved, how can I open that file in a table view to view it as a .pdf or as a .txt file?

I've seen csv videos and it is almost to that nature, but now I would like to see my downloads list and be able to choose which file I want to see.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to view the information as a pdf or txt file? If the information that the user enters only needs to stay within the bounds of the app you do not need to add this information to a pdf or txt file. You can  simply archive it.

Comment: Yes there is reason. The information will not stay within the bounds of the app. I would like to eventually incorporate e-mailing into this app (I have done an test email app already). I would like to e-mail these files from phone to office computer for data logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay everybody! Here is an update to my woes and hopefully this answer will help future developers. Side note: I am new to Stack Overflow so apparently I need 10 reputation to post more than 2 links and I have 1 reputation. So unfortunately, I will break this down. Let's begin!

> By using X Code, how can I save files inside an app I am creating that contains labels and textfields that the User has put their information in?

The answer I found and am happy with is with *Core Data*.

Here is a step by step instruction that I found that creates a Navigation Controller and  UITableView to connect to a View Controller. In that View Controller, I could add, edit, and save multiple UITextField values.

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

App Coda is a good website to do little tasks to understand the fundamental features before you start going to more difficult tasks. 1/3

Comment: Here is a YouTube tutorial as well that encompasses the CoreData that I was doing: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgNq5-go-ws>

Furthermore, once that information is saved, how can I open that file in a table view to view it as a .pdf or as a .txt file? 

My second question was solved in the CoreData tutorial. I cannot view a text file in a separate view. I just ended up using an E-mail button to E-mail myself the TextFields and place commas in between to behave like a CSV (Comma Separated Value). That will make the .txt transition to .xls easier.
2/3

Comment: >I've seen csv videos and it is almost to that nature, but now I would like to see my downloads list and be able to choose which file I want to see. 

What I was trying to get as well is explained in this [picture](http://www.imgur.com/bI12hDv), but I am content with a Table View. Where it displays, 'Browser', 'Downloads', 'Files', 'Settings', is with the Tab Bar features, but I am not in a hurry to do that. That concludes my update. Hope this helps! 3/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty vague question as there are many methods depending on the size and type of data you want to store. For simple text fields as you suggest, NSUserDefaults is lightweight and easy to use, and is useful for storing small strings and such. It also has the benefit of being readable in Xcode as it's a .plist file.

If you need to save it as a text file however, see the Apple documentation for a rough guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html

Edit:
Since you actually want to have a list of multiple files, I would definitely follow the apple documentation guide on writing strings to an URI. Keep in mind .pdf and .txt formats are completely different, with the latter being much easier to implement. You will also have to manage the loading and displaying of the files in a table yourself. You can probably do this by just saving the files into a specific folder in your application support directory and loading from it when needed

Comment: I am sure there are multiple ways to do one task in programming. I'm trying to be as descriptive as possible, so here is a screen shot I took off an app that I am trying to replicate: http://imgur.com/bI12hDv 

The files are listed in a table view and that is what I would like my app to do after the User clicks 'Save'. But instead of .mp4's, they would be either .txts or .pdfs. The User can then view it on their phone or have the ability to send the file as an e-mail. Does that help?